# How do I change the playback speed without changing the tempo?

Tags: audacity

I have a recording in Audacity that I want to slow down *for editing purposes only.* When I'm finished editing and I go to export the file, the file should have the original tempo. Yes, I can go to Effect > "Change Tempo" to change the tempo until the song plays as slow as I want it to, but then I'd have to change the tempo back when I'm done editing the song.

Answer (score 13):

> **Play-at-Speed**
>
> Audacity has a "Play-at-Speed" feature located at Transcription Toolbar. Move the slider to choose a slower or faster
> speed than normal, then click the green triangle button to left of the
> slider to play at that speed.
>
> The benefits of changing speed with Transcription Toobar are that you
> don't have to change the audio data in the track by running an effect,
> or worry about reverting the change if you want to export the project
> at its original speed. (source: https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/play_at_speed_toolbar.html)

[image]

Comment: Is there way to speed up the playback speed without the pitch increasing?

Comment: This slider has no effect for me. (It is simply ignored). Also, your source is dead

Comment: @Winter You have to use the special transcription play button right next to the playback speed slider.  The main play button will always play at normal speed.

Comment: That link seems to be dead. Is  https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/change_speed.html its new location?

Comment: @NetherGranite thanks - new article is here: https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/play_at_speed_toolbar.html

Answer (score 3):

This is a good question. My workaround is to speed up the audio during my edit with Change Tempo. Since I'm editing interviews, I use a lot of labels, but then those labels are synced with the sped-up audio, which is a problem. So, I'll re-import the original, normal-speed track, change tempo on the sped up track with its Labels track sync-locked, and then delete the modified track. The labels should, in theory, line up with the corresponding audio in the original, normal-speed track.

A caveat is to not do any editing of the actual audio, because modifying the track length in any way (i.e. deleting a bit of unwanted audio, or adding silence) will screw everything up when you try to expand the tempo back to the original track length.